# Can't use public void

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is my snippet of code, where I cant seem to use public void. does anybody know what the issue is?

```
package com.demoapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

     // public void

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Comment: `override fun` is an indicator that you are using Kotlin and not Java.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like Kotlin. Kotlin doesn't have `void` keyword.

Try:

```
fun yourFunction() {
    //your code
}
```